# Image scale using aspect ratio coil using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, aspect-ratio, coil

I need to display image from uri/filepath, big image 1300x1600 resolution.
Need to maintain aspect ratio.
i tried with coil but didn't give desirable result, still shows big image. not sure whats wrong
here what i tried

```
val painter =
    rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageUri.value)

Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp, 0.dp, 16.dp, 0.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(painter.intrinsicSize.height / painter.intrinsicSize.width)
)
```

Comment: The issue might be `aspectRatio(painter.intrinsicSize.height / painter.intrinsicSize.width)` try changing to `aspectRatio(painter.intrinsicSize.width / painter.intrinsicSize.height)`

Comment: intrinsicSize itself gives error size unspecified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `size unspecified` if one of view width/height is calculated as zero.

You can use something like:

```
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    contentDescription = "contentDescription",
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp, 0.dp, 16.dp, 0.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .then(
            (painter.state as? AsyncImagePainter.State.Success)
                ?.painter
                ?.intrinsicSize
                ?.let { intrinsicSize ->
                    Modifier.aspectRatio(intrinsicSize.width / intrinsicSize.height)
                } ?: Modifier
        )
)
```

Comment: it crosses the desirable size of Image 200x200 .

Comment: @AndroidDev It is not clear for me. In your code there is `.fillMaxWidth()` modifier. Change it and fix your favorite width with the same code.

Comment: exploring compose sorry.

Comment: just wanted to check can we do that, like fix height and width can we draw image with aspect ratio?